# What exactly does aspnet_compile -v switch do?

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

The `aspnet_compiler` requires `-v` for virtual path (or `-m` from which it derives the virtual path), even when `-p` is specified.

For example:

```
aspnet_compiler -p c:\Projects\WebSites\WebSite3 -v /WebSite3 c:\Precompiled
```

I wonder why the `-v` is important. You can put a bogus path and it will still compile. The value ends up in the `.compiled` files as part of the `virtualPath` attribute. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preserve resultType="8" virtualPath="/WebSite3/global.asax" hash="6c89111" filehash="11b1c8ce4647" flags="150000" assembly="App_global.asax" type="ASP.global_asax">
    <filedeps>
        <filedep name="/WebSite3/global.asax" />
    </filedeps>
</preserve>
```

If installed on a server, the site seems to work fine even with a mismatched (or bogus) `virtualPath` in the `.compiled` file. So is there any good reason `aspnet_compiler` is making a fuss about specifying this?